# Embeddable VM runtime for ANSI C

Tags: c, runtime, embeddable

I'm looking for a Virtual Machine runtime environment that is embeddable in any ANSI C code.

I have designed a syntax for a functional language that looks a lot like a stripped version of  CoffeeScript. Now I want to write a compiler for this language, but I don't have know what VM I should go for.

The key function for my language is support for closures and of course a sane GC. It should be fairly small.

I have been working with Lua in a couple of projects and I'm investigating the Lua 5.1 VM. However, it seems to be tightly coupled with Luas concept of tables which my language wouldn't  utilize.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Most people go for LLVM (and for good reasons). But that's not ANSI C.

Comment: But is LLVM embeddable? Can I for example create a native C application that hosts a LLVM environment?

Comment: As I said, it's not ANSI C. It's C++ actually. And yes, it is embeddable, it's a library actually.

Comment: You could write one?  I doubt there is anything off the shelf that is particularly suited to this task.  Actually see my answer later.  Might solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Parrot?

http://www.parrot.org/

Comment: I will absolutely checkout Parrot!

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [Neko VM](http://nekovm.org/).

Comment: Great! I will investigate Neko aswell!

Comment: I have investigated Neko closely. Seems to have some problems regarding meaningful errormessages in the VM. Other then that it seems to be spot on! I'll take a closer look at parrot.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be [TinyVM](https://github.com/GenTiradentes/tinyvm/) which is very small, and it's codebase is surprisingly clean. The original project also has a forked branch that improves on performance: [FastVM](https://github.com/GenTiradentes/tinyvm/tree/fastvm). Both are pretty powerful for their size, and could easily be extended to best fit your needs.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Definitely an interesting project! Will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Besides many other alternatives, have a look at the [squirrel progamming language and its VM](http://squirrel-lang.org/).